# Should I used DISTRIBUTE BY and SORT BY RAND() to get a fixed number of random samples in a random order in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

To generate a fixed number of random samples in a random order from a large table in various SQL varients, I've used the following syntax:

```
SELECT
[...]
FROM big_tbl
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT k
```

This works in Spark SQL, but, I noticed a colleague using the following:

```
SELECT
[...]
FROM big_tbl
DISTRIBUTE BY RAND()
SORT BY RAND()
LIMIT k
```

- Is one method generally recommend over the other? If the answer is "It depends...", how can I know if one is preferred?

  - In my case, the table has millions of rows and I need thousands of samples.
- If one wants `k` samples and the order in unimportant, can one omit the `SORT BY` clause?

Comment: DISTRIBUTE + SORT seems a bit "prescriptive". It might even repartition ALL the data even though you're only interested in K random rows. I'd be interested in seeing the query plan to compare